# Using a BAT file to merge PDFs with a common filename

Tags: pdf, batch-file

I am using a BAT file to try to automate merging PDFs with a similar filename. I'm kind of new to this, and I think I may be setting my file locations wrong? I'm getting a :Enviorment variable 'x' not defined. I got this from another post, and would appreciate any help:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem source root folder where to crawl pdfs.
set F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0

rem destination folder
set F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0\Merged

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad /o:n "%source%"') do (
        set _pdffiles=

        for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "%%a\*.pdf"') do (
            set _pdffiles=!_pdffiles! "%%i"
            set "_outputpdf=%%~ni"
        )

        echo pdftk.exe !_pdffiles! cat output "%destination%\!_outputpdf:~0,6!.pdf"
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try:

```
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem :: set ful path\file.exe
set "_pdftk=\The_\Full_\Path_\To_\File_\pdftk.exe"

rem :: goto your folder:
cd /d "F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0"

rem  :: set traget file directory
set "_desti=F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0\Merged"

rem :: run in your folder  
for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('echo\"!cd!"')do set "_n=!_desti!\%%~nxi" && ^
    call "!_pdftk!" "%%~dpnxi\*.pdf" cat output "!_n:~0,-6!.pdf"

rem :: run in all subfolder 
for /r /d %%i in (*)do if /i not "%%~nxi"=="Merged" 2>nul (
    set "_n=!_desti!\%%~nxi" && call "!_pdftk!" "%%~dpnxi\*.pdf" cat output "!_n:~0,-6!.pdf"
   )
   
endlocal & goto=:EOF
```

Comment: Okay so this is great because it produces an output! Thank you so much. Only problem is it's a little weird how it exports. I get one PDF named "Merged.PDF" in my "go to folder" that is of the first folder. And then a no name pdf in my "merged" folder, with the combined contents on the last folder's contents. How could I clean up the naming, and get it to go through all of my sub folders?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting two variables actually, use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem source root folder where to crawl pdfs.
set "source=F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0"

rem destination folder
set "destination=F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0\Merged"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad /o:n "%source%"') do (
set _pdffiles=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "%%a\*.pdf"') do (
    set _pdffiles=!_pdffiles! "%%i"
    set "_outputpdf=%%~ni"
)
echo pdftk.exe !_pdffiles! cat output "%destination%\!_outputpdf:~0,6!.pdf"
)
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the initial problem. the command prompt reads: pdftk.exe "11111_ABCD.pdf" "11111_EFGH.pdf" cat output "F:Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Tr...\11111_.pdf". However, no output is actually there. Do I need to make sure that my pdftk.exe is in the same location as this bat file? @Wasif Hasan

Comment: You have two options: 1. Place the exe, and its associated resources especially DLLs in the same location (Not Recommended) 2. Add the location of pdftk.exe to PATH

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Again, I am so new to this... how would I do the #2 option? Do I define it somewhere in my BAT file?

Comment: Yes first in your batch file beginning, enter `setx PATH "%PATH%;PATH OF PDFTK.EXE"` Make sure to replace "PATH OF PDFTK.EXE" to the original path. Or better run it in Cmd.

Comment: Okay, so I did that, but now I'm getting a "truncating to 124 characters" error in the beginning, and file not found at the end of where it lists what my output should be. Any ideas? Again, I really appreciate your help! Do I keep the quotation marks in like you did? Starts at "%PATH% , ends at the end of my exe path?