# BAT file Combining PDF files based on filename

Tags: pdf, batch-file, pdftk

I've been trying to combine PDFs with similar filenames together using a BAT file. I was using the method of using pDFTK shortcut, select PDFs I want to combine, and then "send to" the shortcut. However, I am trying to find a way to automate that within folders/files that have common names. When I run my BAT file, even though it says what the output should be, there is no output. When I tried defining the pdftk.exe file, I get a character limit notice in the beginning (caused by me defining the PDFTK.exe location), and then "file not found" error after the supposed output.  Can you see anything wrong with this, as to why it wouldn't work? I even tried it with the pdftk exe and dll in the same folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem source root folder where to crawl pdfs.
set "source=F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0"

rem destination folder
set "destination=F:\Sabine_To_Galveston_Project\ZZ_File_Transform\154482.0\Merged"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /ad /o:n "%source%"') do (
set _pdffiles=
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /o:n "%%a\*.pdf"') do (
set _pdffiles=!_pdffiles! "%%i"
set "_outputpdf=%%~ni"
)
echo pdftk.exe !_pdffiles! cat output "%destination%\!_outputpdf:~0,6!.pdf"
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a BAT file to merge PDFs with a common filename](https://superuser.com/questions/1590150/using-a-bat-file-to-merge-pdfs-with-a-common-filename)

Answer (score 0):

```all-file-bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

mode 60,3 && color 0a && title <nul && title Merging ...\*.PDF

rem :: check if bat in sendTo folder, also check if argument == false
if not exist "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\%~nx0" (
     cd /d "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo" >nul 2>&1
     <con: copy "%~dpnx0" "!CD!\" && call "%~nx0" "%~1"| endlocal && goto:eof
     )else if "%~1"=="" timeout.exe -1 && echo\Argumment Missing. && goto:eof

rem :: set ful path\file.exe 
set "_pdftk=\The_\Full_\Path_\To_\File_\pdftk.exe"

rem :: check and goto your folder:
>nul 2>nul cd /d "%~dpnx1" || <con: ^< nul ^
     echo\Folder do not exist.. && timeout.exe -1 && goto :^(

rem :: run in your folder  
if exist "!cd!\*.pdf" (
     for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('echo\"!cd!"')do set "_n=%~dpnx1\Merged\%%~nxi" && <nul ^
         call "!_pdftk!" "%%~dpnxi\*.pdf" cat output "!_n:~0,-6!.pdf"
    )

rem :: run in all subfolder 
for /r /d %%i in (*)do echo\"%%~nxi"|find/i /v "Merged" >nul && if exist "%%~i\*.pdf" (
     set "_n=%~dpnx1\Merged\%%~nxi" && call "!_pdftk!" "%%~dpnxi\*.pdf" cat output "!_n:~0,-6!.pdf"
    )

:^(
endlocal & goto=:EOF
```

---

This is for check if the bat itself is in the `\sendto` folder, if the condition is false, will copy it to the `\sendto` folder and call it the execution again passing the same argument o, (if it was passed), if the condition is true, execution continues.

---

- *The option **`/d /r` is undocumented**, but can be a useful combination, while it will **recurse through all subfolders** the wildcard will only match against Folder/Directory names (**not filenames**).*

  - **[Sources ss64.com | `For /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Cd](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[Echo](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)**

  [√] **[Move](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For /D /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && | ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[`Enable/DisableDelayedExpansion` | `Enable/DisableExtensions`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**